# python: How to sum a series using an increment number

Tags: python, sum, series

```
n = int(input('Enter n: '))
count = 1
sum = 0
number = 1
while (count <= n):
    sum = sum + number
    count = count + 1
    number = number + 2
print('Sum =', sum)
```

Is it possible to use the same concept for 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + 25 + 36 + 49 + 64 .... + n

Comment: There is a couple ways of doing this check out this SO question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/39560167/2175781

Comment: This question was asked a few hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460128/write-a-program-to-compute-the-sum-of-the-terms-of-the-series/49460245?noredirect=1#comment85925468_49460245

Is that your account that asked the other?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension to make this more elegant and pythonic:

```
def sum_series(start, end):
  return sum([i**2 for i in range(start, end+1)])

print(sum_series(1,10))
```

Output:

```
385
```

Or using higher order functions:

```
>>> sum(map(lambda x: x**2, range(1,11)))
385
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do

```
n = int(input('Enter n: '))
count = 1
sum = 0
while (count <= n):
  sum = sum + count*count
  print("{s}+".format(s=sum)      
  count = count + 1
print('Sum =', sum)
```

Comment: if n = 100, I want the program to run  1 + 4
+ 9 + 16 + 25 + 36 + 49 + 64 + 81 + 100 and displays the result 385. Is it possible to restrict n so it can stop looping

Comment: @john n=10 then only it will be 100. i have modified my answer